# How to store the list of visited node in a path on a graph in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am studying Prolog and I am finding some difficulty interpreting the slide proposed by my professor.

Starting from the classic program that say if exist a path between two node of a graph, this one:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(a,e).
edge(c,d).
edge(d,e).
edge(f,e).

path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y).

path(X,Y) :- path(X,Z),
             edge(Z,Y).
```

He introduce a new version that use the predicate: **path(X,Y,Path)** that is TRUE if in the graph exist a path between X and Y and if **Path** is the list of visited nodes

So he give me the following new version of the previous program:

```
/* BASE CASE: exist an edge between X and Y, so the Path is
              the couple [X,Y]
*/
path(X,Y,[X,Y]) :- edge(X,Y).

path(X,Y,P) :- path(X,Z,P1),
               edge(Z,Y),
               lastelem(P,Y,P1).
```

The base case is pretty simple: if exist an edge that connect X and Y it is true that exist a path from X to Y and the list of the visited node is [X,Y]

I have some problems with the second rule: if X and Y are not connect by only a single edge, so that there is a path between X and Y, have to exist a path between X and an other node Z (and P1 is the list of the visited node in this path) an an edge that connect Z to the final node Y.

This is pretty simple...the problem is with the last predicate **lastelem/3** that it is not provided in the slide (so I don't know exactly what it do):

```
lastelem(P,Y,P1).
```

I think that it generate P inserting Y  in P1 or something like it...

Do you have some more precise idea about it and a possible implementation of this predicate?

Comment: The base case is actually less simple than it could have been: `path(X, X, [X])`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to re-invent the wheel by writing recursive code yourself.

Simply define a binary relation `edge/2` ...

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(a,e).
edge(c,d).
edge(d,e).
edge(f,e).
```

... and use the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/4609915)!

```
?- path(edge,Path,From,To).
  Path = [To]       , From = To
; Path = [a,b]      , From = a, To = b 
; Path = [a,b,c]    , From = a, To = c
; Path = [a,b,c,d]  , From = a, To = d
; Path = [a,b,c,d,e], From = a, To = e
; Path = [b,c]      , From = b, To = c
; Path = [b,c,d]    , From = b, To = d
; Path = [b,c,d,e]  , From = b, To = e
; Path = [a,e]      , From = a, To = e
; Path = [c,d]      , From = c, To = d
; Path = [c,d,e]    , From = c, To = e
; Path = [d,e]      , From = d, To = e
; Path = [f,e]      , From = f, To = e 
; false.
```

Answer (score 0):

The professor probably wants to append `Y` to `P`:

```
lastelem(Lst0, X, Lst) :-
    append(Lst0, [X], Lst).
```

[That's a pretty stupid idea, though, since appending to a list takes linear time. A constant-time solution is to prepend the element:

```
% I wouldn't actually write a predicate for this, but nevertheless:
lastelem(Lst, X, [X|Lst]).
```

This gives the path in reverse order, but a single `reverse/2` solves that.]

Comment: The first one don't work: if I launch the query I obtain this error message: 
[debug]  ?- path(a,d, Path).
ERROR: Out of local stack
   Exception: (1,597,352) path(a, _G488, _G489) ?

Comment: same problem with the second version :-(

Comment: @AndreaNobili: then the search gets stuck in a cycle. Try it on a graph without cycles.

Comment: it seems to me that this graph (rappresented by the edges of my previous example) have not cycles...

Comment: yes and the problem seems to be in the lastelem predicate and not in the path predicate that work well...

Comment: @AndreaNobili: now I see. The recursive clause for `path` should call `edge` before going into recursion.

Comment: mmm, I think that I have solved in this way: lastelem(P, Y, P1) :- append(P1, [Y], P).

Comment: seems to work well infact with te previous graph I have that:
[debug]  ?- path(a,d,Path).
Path = [a, b, c, d] 

And it is correct: P is the final Path, P1 is the subpath foun and Y is the element to add...so I have to append Y to P1 to obtain P...I think that this is correct

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like:

```
path(X,Y,Path) :-
  path(X,Y,T) ,
  reverse(T,Path)
  .

path( X , Y , [] ) :- % a path exists between X and Y:
  connected(X,Y)      % - if they are directly connected
  .                   %
path( X , Y , P  ) :- % a path exists between X and Y:
  connected(X,T) ,    % - if X is connected to another node (T)
  T \= Y ,            % - and T is not the destination (Y)
  not visited(T,P) ,  % - and T has not yet been visited
  path(T,Y, [X|P])    % - and a path exists between T and Y
  .                   %

connected(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y) . % two nodes are connected if they are
connected(X,Y) :- edge(Y,X) . % if they are adjacent adjacent.

visited(X,[X|Xs]) :- ! .             % a node is visited
visited(X,[_|Xs]) :- visited(X,Xs) . % if it exists in the list of already-visited nodes
```

Comment: I have to use the posted version because, later, he develop it further adding other features